Как удалить заголовки ответа?
Пытаюсь удалить заголовки ответа, но они почему-то не удаляются. Использую расширение "Resource Override" и он удаляет. Как мне самому удалить их? Использую вторую версию
chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(details => {
    const headers = details.responseHeaders.filter(header => 
        !['Content-Security-Policy', 'X-Content-Security-Policy', 'X-Frame-Options'].includes(header.name)
    );

    headers.push({
        name: 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin',
        value: '*'
    });

    return {responseHeaders: headers};
}, {urls: ['<all_urls>']}, ['responseHeaders', 'blocking'])


добавь логи. проверь что в этот обработчик вообще заходит

Объект с заголовками приходит

а откуда ты взял пример обработчика? Почему ты думаешь, что он должен что-то вернуть, а не изменить in-place?

Все, я решил. В ответ он возвращает название заголовок в нижем регистре

стоит написать свой ответ с пример как решил проблему и описанием в чем была проблема
